# How to let a kotlin block return void?

Tags: android, kotlin

like code below, when I use a block to callback,and I want to let the block return void, but I can not find a word to do this.

`fun search(key:String, callback: ((novels:ResultInfo)->??)){`

Answer (score 7):

```
fun search(key: String, callback: (novels: ResultInfo) -> Unit): Unit { ... }
```

See [Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html)

I also declared the function to return effectively void

Comment: `Unit` is the word to indicate that function returns a `void`. This answer should be marked as correct